# Java : Datastructure to stock lots of words

Tags: java, data-structures

I have to stock lots of word (+200k) in a Java program and I want to access them really fast.
I just need to know if a given word belongs to my "dictionary". I don't need a pair like `<word, smthg>`.
If possible I'm searching a solution in the standard library.

PS : Maybe using a data structure is not the better way to do this ? Reading each time the file containing the words will be more efficient ?

edit : It's a small project. I have to deal with effectiveness and the memory

Last Edit : I finally choose HashSet.

Comment: Sounds like a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) could be a good fit.

Comment: Do u have any idea about using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)

Comment: @Keppil The problem in HashSet is that it is not sorted. So searching will be slower.

Comment: @Nikhil: Finding a word in a `HashSet` is `O(1)`, as opposed to a `TreeSet`, where it is `O(log n)`

Comment: HashSet is really faster. Thanks

Comment: @Yavar: I thought The Problem is with millions of data..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use java Sets because sets are linear sorted data structure like TreeSet. So for searching, techniques like binary search can be implemented and they are fast with no repetition.

This is the structure of a java Sets.

[image]

Also it will not going to allow duplication hence reducing redundancy and will save your memory.

If you want to know various searching algorithms complexities refer this link. Here is

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Sets will waste a lot of memory. There are specialized data structures for this kind of tasks.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev 200k words of 10 characters on average, stored in a HashSet, will maybe take 5 to 10MB in memory. That is not a lot...

Comment: @assylias Ya that is what searching will be much fast because sets are sorted and you can apply many techniques to them.

Comment: As for performance, filling a hashset with 200k words and running 1 million word lookups takes about 150ms in total on my desktop pc.

Comment: Everyone search in a Particia or Trie is at least as efficient. There are specialized data structures for working with strings.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I'm not saying that HashSet is more efficient than specialised data structures - I'm just saying that it will be good enough for the OP's requirement. So it is probably not worth bothering to find and import external libraries or, worse, manually implement those structures.

Comment: @assylias Can I have your mail Id or TwitterID.

Comment: And what about the loading time of these 200k words in that kind of structure ?

Comment: It takes less than 1second to load and check each word with an HashSet. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Nikhil I generally don't share my email but feel free to leave a comment here.

Comment: @assylias My mail ID is nikhilagrawal60@gmail.com, Twitter -- _nikhilagrawal

Answer (score 3):

Use either a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [Patricia tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) depending on the distribution of the words. I would personally go with Patricia tree as it is more optimized for memory usage(though it is harder to implement).

Comment: For a fairly small amount of objects like in the OP's use case, a HashSet would do just fine. Also worth noting there are no Trie/Patricia Tree implementations in the standard JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like to test my `TrieMap` or `TrieSet` implementations ([found here](https://gist.github.com/klatu/5360669))? I've written them specifically for cases like this one. So far I have implemented Tries for `String` and `byte[]` keys.

```
    TrieSet<String> t = Tries.newStringTrieSet();

    t.add("hello");
    t.add("help");
    t.add("hell");
    t.add("helmet");
    t.add("hemp");

    List<String> resultsA = new ArrayList<>();
    t.findElements("hel", true, resultsA);    // search for prefix

    List<String> resultsB = new ArrayList<>();
    t.findElements("ell", false, resultsB);   // search for substring

    System.out.println("A: " + resultsA);
    System.out.println("B: " + resultsB);
```

This would print:

```
A: [hell, hello, helmet, help]
B: [hell, hello]
```

Comment: >1.5 KLOC and not a single test?

Answer (score 0):

This look quite ok to me, I dont know if I'm wrong for some reason:

```
//put all your words to an ArrayList and sort the list.
List <String> arr = new Arraylist<>();
while(there is next)
    arr.add(theWord)
Collections.sort(arr);

//this is your search method
boolean mysearch(keyword){
    return Collections.binarySearch(arr, keyword)
}
```

The performance is: `O(n*log_n)` for inserting data and search is `O(log_n)`

Let say, each string is 20B, on the average. `20B *200000 = 4MB` space.